Airplane mode won’t turn off and I can’t connect to WiFi or LAN
I’m in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and I have tried everything to disable airplane mode so I can connect to WiFi but nothing seems to work. Before changing the OS, the network worked just fine in Windows. I don’t know what to do or how to fix this problem.
Help will be kindly appreciated
My laptop’s model is: HP Pavilion 11-n076eg x360

When you say you’ve ‘tried everything’ - could you let us know all the things you’ve tried? There’s no point us suggesting things you’ve done already. Thanks.

I have tried turning it off and I have searched everything how to turn it off and I can’t find anything
